# System error after Kali Linux dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, upgrade, kali-linux

I was doing a distribution upgrade on **Kali** from 1. 1. 0 to 2. 0 using:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Upgrade was of 2 GB and after downloading 1 GB, and I wanted to download `openssh-server` so I did an `apt-get install`, but an upgrade message was shown (`apt-get upgrade`) instead.

Since it required only 74 MB/1 GB download, I preferred to do it first, and after installation, I rebooted my laptop and was welcomed with this message:

[image]

I can't login into GUI mode but CLI mode is available. I have no idea how to fix it.

P.S.: During installation I was asked for some greeting file, it said to choose between downloaded or system file along with a message that system file was modified, so I preferred to choose system file.

Answer (score 0):

You could re-configure all the packages again.

> sudo dpkg --reconfigure -a

May be it will work for you. If not then you will need to re-format your system with the latest version of Kali Linux.

hope it helps

Comment: I dont think reformatting is an option for me, i have tried installing 2.0 and it doesnt load kernel modules in my laptop